# Let $A$ be positive definite, show that there is $S\in \operatorname{GL}(n, \mathbb{R})$ such that $A=SS^T$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-decomposition

> Let $A$ be positive definite, show that there is $S\in
>  \operatorname{GL}(n, \mathbb{R})$ such that $A=SS^T$

I know that this hints at the Cholesky decomposition. But I don't have to prove that $A$ can be decomposed into a lowever triangular matrix and its conjugate but rather that a decomposition exists.

I know that $A$ is positive definite  iff $x^TAx>0$. This is not much to work with. Another way of characterizing A positive definite Matrix is by looking at its Eigenvalues which all have to be greater than zero. This is a dead end for me too. Can anyone give me a hint?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you write down the eigendecomposition $A=UDU^\top$ where $U$ is orthogonal and $D$ is diagonal, you can define $D^{1/2}$ to be the result of taking the square root of each entry of $D$ (this is possible because the eigenvalues are positive). Then check that $S=UD^{1/2} U^\top$ works.

Comment: Best hint ever xD

Comment: Wait, is A even diagonalizable? Doesn't A have to be symmetric?

Comment: @Analysis [Spectral theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectral_theorem)